# WebAPI Selfhost: Can't bind multiple parameters to the request's content

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

The below code are simplified to show the necessity. May I know what is wrong? I can't seems to retrieve two Parameters (A and B in this case) using the [FromBody] attribute.

The error message is "Can't bind multiple parameters ('A' and 'B') to the request's content"

It is perfectly fine if I have either A or B only.

Web API:

```
[Route("API/Test"), HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody] int A, [FromBody] int B)
```

Client:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
    new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "A", "123" },
        { "B", "456" }
    });
client.PostAsync("http://localhost/API/Test", content).Result;
```

Answer (score 68):

Web Api doesn't support multiple [FromBody] params I think. But you can use Api model, to passing more parameters to your api action.:

```
public class YourApiModel
{
    public int A{ get; set; }

    public int B { get; set; }

    //...other properties    
}
```

After that, you can simply use this in your API controller Test:

```
    // POST: api/test
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] YourApiModel model)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Just to confirm what you've said, the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) says "At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body"

Answer (score 12):

Try the Web API code:

```
[DataContract]
public class Model
{
    [DataMember]
    public int A { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int B { get; set; }
}

[Route("API/Test"), HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromUri] Model model)
```

Answer (score 0):

experienced a similar error while developing a c# REST Web API for Active Directory Authentication, see my error message below.

{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Can't bind multiple parameters ('userName' and 'passWord') to the request's content.",
"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"
}

I was able to resolve it using the below code

```
// code with issue 
[HttpPost]
        // POST:  api/Showcredential
        public string Post([FromBody]string userName, [FromBody]string passWord)
        {
            return "Username: " + userName +" " + "Password: " + passWord;
        }




// code used to resolve the issue

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ActiveDirectoryRESTApi.Controllers
{

    
    public class ShowCredentialController : ApiController
    {


        public class Loginparam
        {
            public object username { get; set; }
            public object password { get; set; }
        }



        [HttpPost]


        public object Post([FromBody()] object Loginvalues)
        {

            var sessionresponse = new Loginparam();
            string rawrequest = Loginvalues.ToString();
            var jsonResulttodict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(rawrequest);
            string rsusername = jsonResulttodict["username"].ToString();
            string rspassword = jsonResulttodict["password"].ToString();


            return "Username: " + rsusername + " " + "Password: " + rspassword;

            
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a generic class to manage all data type as list, to send everything.
then on your body i can, for example:

> int=1,int=3,int=5,string=fdsg,bool=0,ecc...

```
[HttpPost]
public object Post([FromBody] Generic values)
{
    return values.String;
}

public class Generic
{
    public List<Nullable<byte>> Byte { get; set; }
    public List<Nullable<sbyte>> Sbyte { get; set; }
    public List<Nullable<short>> Short { get; set; }
    public List<Nullable<ushort>> Ushort { get; set; }
    public List<Nullable<int>> Int { get; set; }
    public List<Nullable<uint>> Uint { get; set; }
    public List<Nullable<long>> Long { get; set; }
    public List<Nullable<ulong>> Ulong { get; set; }
    public List<Nullable<float>> Float { get; set; }
    public List<Nullable<double>> Double { get; set; }
    public List<Nullable<decimal>> Decimal { get; set; }
    public List<Nullable<char>> Char { get; set; }
    //public List<object> Object { get; set; }
    public List<string> String { get; set; }
    public List<Nullable<DateTime>> Datetime { get; set; }

    //public List<bool> Bool { get; set; }
    //to mange also 0/1
    public List<string> Bool { get; set; }
    private List<Nullable<bool>> Boolean
    {
        get
        {
            List<Nullable<bool>> tmp_b = new List<Nullable<bool>>();

            foreach (string tmp in Bool)
            {
                switch (tmp.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "TRUE":
                    case "1":
                        tmp_b.Add(true);
                        break;
                    case "FALSE":
                    case "0":
                        tmp_b.Add(false);
                        break;
                    default:
                        tmp_b.Add(null);
                        break;
                }
            }
            return tmp_b;
        }
    }
```