# Web API not parsing get parameters correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following url

```
    http://localhost/api/map/tmc/identify?
    geometry={x:-112.0469856262207,y:33.3926093953406, spatialReference:{wkid:4326}}
    &geometryType=esriGeometryPoint
    &mapExtent={xmin:-112.18062400817871,ymin:33.33956359362892,xmax:-111.95076942443848,ymax:33.49201883920683, spatialReference:{wkid:4326}}
    &tolerance=5
    &sr=4326
    &imageDisplay=1340,1065,96
    &layers=all:0
    &returnGeometry=true
    &returnM=false
```

I am trying to intercept that object using the following action

```
    public class SpatialReference
    {
        public int wkid { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geometry
    {
        public double x { get; set; }
        public double y { get; set; }
        public SpatialReference spatialReference { get; set; }
    }

    public class MapExtent
    {
        public double xmin { get; set; }
        public double ymin { get; set; }
        public double xmax { get; set; }
        public double ymax { get; set; }
        public SpatialReference spatialReference { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public string geometryType { get; set; }
        public MapExtent mapExtent { get; set; }
        public int tolerance { get; set; }
        public int sr { get; set; }
        public List<int> imageDisplay { get; set; }
        public string layers { get; set; }
        public bool returnGeometry { get; set; }
        public bool returnM { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/map/tmc/identify")]
    public object Identify([FromUri]RootObject root)
    {
        return root;
    }
```

And I get back

```
{  
   "geometry":{  
      "x":0.0,
      "y":0.0,
      "spatialReference":null
   },
   "geometryType":"esriGeometryPoint",
   "mapExtent":{  
      "xmin":0.0,
      "ymin":0.0,
      "xmax":0.0,
      "ymax":0.0,
      "spatialReference":null
   },
   "tolerance":5,
   "sr":4326,
   "imageDisplay":[  
      0
   ],
   "layers":"all:0",
   "returnGeometry":true,
   "returnM":false
}
```

as you can see the tolerance and sr were set correctly but the objects were not. Unfortunately I have no control over the request (It's always a GET and in this format). How can I correctly parse the url into the right objects

Answer (score 2):

Since you have 9 query parameters in your http GET, you should declare 9 arguments in the action method instead of a root object i.e:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/map/tmc/identify")]
public object Identify([FromUri]Geometry geometry, 
    [FromUri]string geometryType, 
    [FromUri] MapExtent mapExtent,
    ...)
```

`[FromUri]RootObject root` will not map the parameters correctly since they are query parameters and **not a** POST body

Comment: I tried this originally and it said `Can't bind multiple parameters` which brought me to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715230/webapi-selfhost-cant-bind-multiple-parameters-to-the-requests-content which said to use a rootobject but then again that was for a post.

I did just now try just try`[FromUri] Geometry geometry` but I am still getting `{
"x": 0,
"y": 0,
"spatialReference": null
}`