# @Ajax.ActionLink works, but $.ajax doesn't

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to MVC and Ajax, but have good working knowledge and experience with C#.

As a test, I have created an ApiController with 4 methods, 2 using GET and 2 using POST.

All 4 methods work perfectly fine with @Ajax.ActionLink, but (to my best knowledge) equivalent $.ajax call fails POST (but passes GET).

Here is my ApiController:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet] // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [HttpGet] // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return $"id={id}, ~id={~id}";
    }

    [HttpPost] // POST api/values
    public string PostData(string value="123")
    {
        var x = Request;
        return new string(value.Reverse().ToArray());
    }

    [HttpPost] // POST api/values
    public JsonResult<object> PostData(string value, int i)
    {

        return Json((object)new { s=new string(value.Reverse().ToArray()), i });
    }
}
```

And the corresponding calls from .cshtml file:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click me for Get()", "Get", "api/Values", null, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", OnSuccess = "res0", OnFailure = "fail0", UpdateTargetId = "status0" })
<script language="javascript">
    function res0(res) {
        $('#status00')[0].innerText = "Result: " + res;
    }
    function fail0(a, b, c) {
        $('#status000')[0].innerText = "Error\n" + b + '\n' + c;
    }
</script>
<form action="" id="form0">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="status0"></div>
<div id="status00"></div>
<div id="status000"></div>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Click me for Get(5)", "Get", "api/Values", new { id = 5 }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", OnSuccess = "res1", OnFailure = "fail1", UpdateTargetId = "status1" })
<script language="javascript">
    function res1(res) {
        $('#status11')[0].innerText = "Result: " + res;
    }
    function fail1(a, b, c) {
        $('#status111')[0].innerText = "Error\n" + b + '\n' + c;
    }
</script>
<form action="" id="form1">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="status1"></div>
<div id="status11"></div>
<div id="status111"></div>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Click me for PostData('Hello')", "PostData", "api/Values", new { value = "Hello" }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "res2", OnFailure = "fail2", UpdateTargetId = "status2" })
<script language="javascript">
    function res2(res) {
        $('#status22')[0].innerText = "Result: " + res;
    }
    function fail2(a, b, c) {
        $('#status222')[0].innerText = "Error\n" + b + '\n' + c;
    }
</script>
<form action="" id="form2">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="status2"></div>
<div id="status22"></div>
<div id="status222"></div>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Click me for PostData(\"Hello\", 3)", "PostData", "api/Values", new { value = "Hello", i = 3 }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "res3", OnFailure = "fail3", UpdateTargetId = "status3" })
<script language="javascript">
    function res3(res) {
        $('#status33')[0].innerText = "Result: " + JSON.stringify(res);
    }
    function fail3(a, b, c) {
        $('#status333')[0].innerText = "Error\n" + b + '\n' + c;
    }
</script>
<form action="" id="form3">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="status3"></div>
<div id="status33"></div>
<div id="status333"></div>

<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById('form0').onsubmit = function (e) { e.preventDefault(); form0_submit(); };
    document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit = function (e) { e.preventDefault(); form1_submit(); };
    document.getElementById('form2').onsubmit = function (e) { e.preventDefault(); form2_submit(); };
    document.getElementById('form3').onsubmit = function (e) { e.preventDefault(); form3_submit(); };

    function form0_submit() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/api/Values/Get',
            success: function (res) {
                $('#status0')[0].innerText = res;
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, tStatus, errThrown) {
                $('#status00')[0].innerText = tStatus;
                $('#status000')[0].innerText = errThrown;
            }
        });
    }

    function form1_submit() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/api/Values/Get',
            data: {id:@DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Seconds},
            success: function (res) {
                $('#status1')[0].innerText = res;
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, tStatus, errThrown) {
                $('#status11')[0].innerText = tStatus;
                $('#status111')[0].innerText = errThrown;
            }
        });
    }

    function form2_submit() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/Values/PostData',
            data: JSON.stringify({ value: "Test string" }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (res) {
                $('#status2')[0].innerText = res;
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, tStatus, errThrown) {
                $('#status22')[0].innerText = tStatus;
                $('#status222')[0].innerText = errThrown;
            }
        });
    }

    function form3_submit() {
        // not implemented yet, need to get form2_submit() working
    }
</script>
```

I used to get a `404 - Not found` error until in `public string PostData(string value="123")` I made `value` an optional parameter.
Now the function is called with the default `"123"` value, not what I pass it.
In `form2_submit()` I tried different combinations for the `data` parameter.

Analysing the response using the Chrome developer tools (right-click->Inspect, then `Network` tab), I can see that the `ActionLink` sends the parameters as `Query String Parameters`, while the `$.ajax` call does it as `Request Payload` or `Form Data` depending on exactly what I pass to `data` parameter. In both cases, the parameter name/value pair is correct, but the C# ApiController seems to ignore that value (I have tried [FromBody] attribute as well).

I've checked other posts here and on other sites, but cannot figure out why the data is being transmitted differently

Edit:

As requested, the output of `Get-Package`:

```
PM> Get-Package

Id                                  Versions         ProjectName
--                                  --------         -----------
Antlr                               {3.4.1.9004}     WebApplication1
bootstrap                           {3.0.0}          WebApplication1
jQuery                              {1.10.2}         WebApplication1
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights       {2.2.0}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Ag... {2.0.6}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.De... {2.2.0}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Pe... {2.2.0}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web   {2.2.0}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Wi... {2.2.0}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Wi... {2.2.0}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc                {5.2.3}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor              {3.2.3}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization   {1.1.3}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi             {5.2.3}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client      {5.2.3}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core        {5.2.3}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage    {5.2.3}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost     {5.2.3}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages           {3.2.3}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotN... {1.0.8}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax   {3.2.5}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.Net.Compilers             {2.4.0}          WebApplication1
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure        {1.0.0.0}        WebApplication1
Modernizr                           {2.6.2}          WebApplication1
Newtonsoft.Json                     {6.0.4}          WebApplication1
Respond                             {1.2.0}          WebApplication1
WebGrease                           {1.5.2}          WebApplication1

PM>
```

Comment: Can you post the output if the following command `Get-Package` from your NuGet console

Comment: You are sending the request to /api/Values/Get, try sending a get to /api/Values only.

Comment: @Hackerman, if it makes a difference, all NuGet packages had been updated to the latest versions, but I will post the output once I get home.

Comment: @WeslleyRamos, GET works fine, it's POST that is having trouble. I had played with different C# function names and adding `ActionName` attribute, so I doubt `Get` (as in the action name) is an issue. I could try if you insist though, but again, it's POST not working, GET is fine...

Comment: Can you paste here what you see in the network tab of developer tools of your browser? I'm pretty sure that there's a hint of what is going wrong there. edit: (I mean a picture of the screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, If the parameter of your web api method is a simple type like `string` or `int`, Web API tries to get the value from the uri.

If you are sending the string in the request body, you should explicitly use the `FromBody` attribute decorator so that web api know it should read the data from the request body. When `FromBody` attribute is present, web api will use the `content-type` header value to pick a formatter which will work with the content it received.

```
[HttpPost] // POST api/values
public string PostData([FromBody]string value)
{
    if (value == null) value = "some non null";
    var x = Request;
    return new string(value.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

Now on the client side, make sure you are sending JSON string version of the string you want to send, while specifying the content type as `application/json`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/Values/PostData',
    data: JSON.stringify("My Test string"),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (res)
    {
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, tStatus, errThrown)
    {
        console.log(errThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Shyju, that indeed was my issue. I tried the last function on my own and stumbled upon `Ca't bind multiple parameters ('value' and 'i') to the request's content.` exception and found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715230/webapi-selfhost-cant-bind-multiple-parameters-to-the-requests-content), which explains why a far more complex object was happily recognised from the body automatically (different project), but a simple `string` wasn't. I was trying to find documentation for `$.ajax`, turns out I just had to read more on `ApiController`